# Limit of infinite Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be an integrable function.

It is also known that the next limit exists and is finite, and is
equal to $A$: $$\lim_{t\to
 1^{-}}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1})=A$$

> Prove: $$\int_0^1f=A$$

$$$$
Well the sum looks similar to a Riemann sum, and the $\lim_{t\to1^-}$ is similar to Abel's summation, but for the Riemann sum part, I couldn't derive a good partition to the interval $[0,1]$ and didn't know how to use Abel's summation to solve this.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio yes but how does this partition stands with the limit when $t\to 1^-$?

Comment: To the person who voted to close it for "off topic - missing context", how does this missing context or off topic?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, maybe I didn't explain myself properly. Derive a good partition meaning I couldn't tie the partition to the sum with the limit of $t$ going to $1$. For the "lacks any attempt on your side$, how do you know I haven't tried solving it? Again (as you have answered to another question of mine, and as I commented on your answer) - trivial is a subjective concept, what is trivial for you is not trivial for other people.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Shouldn't $N\to \infty$ be taken before $t\to 1^-$?
If so it is correct saying that after taking the limit on $N$, we get this expression: $\lim_{t\to 1^-}\int_0^tf$, and then taking the limit of $1$ gives as $\int_0^1f$? Does taking the limits one after the other in that fashion is correct?

Comment: Why do people want to close this topic? MSE is weird sometimes.

Comment: Very good question indeed. And a very good answer from @zhw. +1 for both the question as well as the answer.

Comment: Also don't worry for close votes. This question is bound to be reopened if it gets closed by mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is really happening in this problem: Let's extend the definition of a partition of $[0,1]$ to allow, in addition to the finite partitions that we know and love, sets $P$ of the form $P = \{a_n: n=0,1,2, \dots \},$ where $1=a_0>a_1 > a_2 > \cdots \to 0.$ Given such a $P,$ define $\mu(P)= \min \{a_n- a_{n+1}: n= 0,1,2,\dots\}.$

Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[0,1].$ If we have an "infinite partition" $P$ as above, then we can define

$$S(P,f) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f(a_n)(a_n-a_{n+1}).$$

This series converges, in fact absolutely.

Claim: If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1],$ then

$$\lim_{\mu(P)\to 0} S(P,f) = \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx,$$

where the limit is taken over infinite partitions $P$ of $[0,1].$

None of this should be surprising. I'm going to leave the proof of this to the reader. Basically, you compare these fancier sums $S(P,f)$ to the finite Riemann sums you already know. It's pretty straightforward, but there is some bookkeeping to do.

So in the problem at hand, we would take $a_n = t^n, n=0,1,2,\dots$ Call this infinite partition $P_t.$ Then $\mu(P_t) = 1-t.$ It follows from the claim that

$$\lim_{t\to 1^-} S(P_t,f) = \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx.$$

This is the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and thorough answer!

Comment: Thank you, it's also been very helpful to me! I would have three questions:
1) Shouldn't it be $\mu(P)= \max \{a_n- a_{n+1}: n= 0,1,2,\dots\}$?
2) Do these "fancier sums" $S(P,f)$ have a particular name in the literature?
3) Could you point out a textbook or set of lecture notes in which these sums with infinite partitions are discussed (including the claim in your answer above)?
It would be great to hear back from you!